# Перевод части ветки на master

Tags: git

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно перенести часть ветки и/или последние изменения на ветку мастер. (желательно с сохранением имени)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким образом.

1) переключаемся на нужную ветку.

2) делаем git reset --soft HEAD~1

3) git stash

4) git branch -m {current_branch_name} {new_branch_name} как нибудь переименуем ветку

5) создаем ветку от мастер с нужным названием как всегда.

6) git stash apply

7) при необходимости решаем конфликты и коммитим

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, можно проще, но наиболее очевидным мне кажется такой вариант:

```sh
# Переходим на branch-2 и создаём новую ветку.
$ git checkout branch-2
$ git checkout -b branch-2-new

# Переносим новую ветку до branch-1.
$ git rebase --onto master branch-1

# Переходим на branch-3 и создаём новую ветку.
$ git checkout branch-3
$ git checkout -b branch-3-new

# Переносим новую ветку до branch-2.
$ git rebase --onto branch-2-new branch-2
```