# GIT: дубликат ветки

Tags: git

Есть ветка мастер, от которой я начал создавать свои ветки по названию задач. Эти задачи я отправляю на одобрение сотруднику, создаю Pull Request. Но из-за того, что мои задачи не утверждаются, соответственно я не получаю разрешение на мердж ветки задачи с веткой мастер. Я создаю новую ветку, но не с мастера а с предыдущей задачи - это плохо, так быть не должно! Таким образом у меня появился большой "паровоз" из веток, которые являются продолжением предыдущих веток. Я жду команды разрешения на мердж, чтобы вернуться к мастеру, и по нормальному продолжить работать.

Я так подумал, можно ли мне создать сейчас ветку, от мастера, продублировать последний комит завершенной задачи и продолжить работать не дожидаясь одобрения пулл-реквеста.

Схематически я нарисовал разветвления. Можно ли ветку 569 продублировать в ветку 570? Чтобы потом после разрешения смерджить 569 с мастером, а с 570 продолжить работать...[image: схема разветвления веток]

Comment: Перечитал вопрос три раза, но так и не понял, что требуется.  Попробуйте посмотреть похожий вопрос [вон там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1068508/180092).

Comment: набрався смелости я создал ветку 570 из мастера, и смерджил туда ветку 569. Всё получилосьтепрь я ожидаю пока мне апрувят мой пулл-реквест, и продолжаю выполнять задачу но уже с новой ветки 570

Comment: очень похоже, что вопрос скорее не о программе git и её возможностях, а о допустимости тех или иных действий в регламенте работы, принятом в организации, где работает автор вопроса. в таком случае обращаться надо к непосредственному начальнику, а не сюда.